# Understanding resource usage with node.js, express and nedb

Tags: node.js, express, nedb

I have created a very simple node.js express application.

It loads about 1 gig of JSON data into a memoryonly nedb database.

So I'm wondering what happens when I try to run this in production?

I don't know how express is deployed but presumably using some sort of web server that executes multiple express processes?

I am wondering if this means that each process will have its own one gigabyte nedb database in memory?

Is there a way to configure such that the one nedb database is shared amongst all the node.js express processes?

Answer (score 0):

it's might not the answer that you expected but it might help.
to observe how much you application use the resources you can use https://keymetrics.io  
it also provide a nodejs module named pm2 that supports clustering for nodejs